# Bootstrap navbar not responding on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Yehee-Lounge</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#top">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#features">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#features">Learn Yeehee</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#features">Courses</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#features">Events</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#features">Impression</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#features">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link scroll" href="#features">Newsletter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button> -->
                </div>
            </nav>
```

this is my simple navbar from bootstrap 4, and below is the problem. When I reduce the width of the screen, "learn yeehee" increse the height of navbar before collapse which I want it to stay at same height till the collapse. How to achieve this. ? Please look the below linked pictures

**Before collapse:**

[image: before collapse]

**During collapse:**

[image: during collapse]

**After Collapse:**

[image: after collapse]

Comment: Did you tried to reduce text-size a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wraps like that (forcing two words of a menu item onto two lines) is simply because there is not enough space on the screen.

So, you have 2 basic options:

1) Replace `navbar-expand-sm` with `navbar-expand-lg`. That will ensure enough space and prevent the issue.

2) Reduce the number of items in your menu by moving some of them into a drop-down (or to a footer area).

Comment: There's actually a third option I just posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486646/8270343 That might not be what you want, but that's an option for when you do need lots of items in the navbar.