# Bootstrap 4 Navbar <li> List

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I need some help with the bootstrap Navbar (Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.3).

What do I have to change so that the button text is single-line and not among each other. When the line is full, the other buttons should start on the left of the next line.

Currently I use this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row w-100 no-gutters d-lg-block d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand col-lg-3 col-7 py-lg-3 order-lg-1 order-2 float-left d-block" href="#">
                Project Name
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-text col-lg-6 col-12 order-lg-2 order-1 text-right float-right align-self-end">Fix Nav Info</div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed float-right order-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all-pages-176" aria-controls="all-pages-176" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="all-pages-176" class="navbar-collapse collapse float-right col-lg-12 order-4" style="height: auto;">
                <ul id="menu-all-pages" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Stylesheets:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .nav-item {
        float: left;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 3px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 1px solid #605555;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px; 
    }
}
```

The Result:

[image: my result]

it should be so

[image: shoul be so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the effect you are looking for, you just need to add the `d-lg-inline-block` class to the `ul` element:

It turns list items into inline-block elements from the large (lg) breakpoint onwards which is what makes them wrap the way you described.

Here's the full, working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .nav-item {
            font-size: 13px;
            margin: 3px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 1px solid #605555;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            line-height: 8px;
        }
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row w-100 no-gutters d-lg-block d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand col-lg-3 col-7 py-lg-3 order-lg-1 order-2 float-left d-block" href="#">
                Project Name
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-text col-lg-6 col-12 order-lg-2 order-1 text-right float-right align-self-end">Fix Nav Info</div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed float-right order-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all-pages-176" aria-controls="all-pages-176" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="all-pages-176" class="navbar-collapse collapse float-right col-lg-12 order-4" style="height: auto;">
                <ul id="menu-all-pages" class="navbar-nav d-lg-inline-block ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item float-left"><a class="nav-link" href="link.php/">Link Text Here</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: aaah, great. Many Thanks. that's what I wanted it to be. works great.

Comment: I just updated my code snippet to add `line-height: 8px;` in order to match the look from your screenshot more closely. Feel free to give me an upvote if you like it. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I made the picture so you can see what I mean. ; o) I did not find the code for the line break. the stylesheets I still fit in total.

Comment: Well, the reason is: Those aren't really line breaks. That's just the flexbox trying to fit as many items as possible and when there are too many to fit on one line, it tried to split words like that. Anyway, just using that native Bootstrap 4 class does the job to achieve the effect you are looking for.